# Can certain arguments not be specified in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my player_player function I want to call the check_win function so that I can declare a winner in this game of connect four. I feel that the way I set up my code only works if I input a certain argument. I wanted to know if it is possible to only input the value for the variable *token* in my code. 
(sorry if this is a redundant question, I'm a beginner in python)

```
def check_win(token, i, j):
    if i-3 in range(0, 6) and j+3 in range(0,5):
        if board[i][j] == token and board[i-1][j+1] == token and board[i-2][j+2] == token and board[i-3][j+3] == token:
            return True
    if i-3 in range(0, 6) and j-3 in range(0,5):
        if board[i][j] == token and board[i-1][j-1] == token and board[i-2][j-2] == token and board[i-3][j-3] == token:
            return True
    if j+3 in range(0, 5):
        if board[i][j] == token and board[i][j+1] == token and board[i][j+2] == token and board[i][j+3] == token:
            return True
    if i-3 in range(0, 6):
        if board[i][j] == token and board[i-1][j] == token and board[i-2][j] == token and board[i-3][j] == token:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Hi Emily - the amount of code you've included here isn't sufficient to determine the answer to your question. In particular, it's unclear what exactly the token values are supposed to be. Perhaps you could include more code and/or explain more clearly what each piece of code is trying to do and what each variable is meant to be?

Comment: (Looking at this a little more, perhaps what you would want to do is use `for` loops to loop over the range of all possible values for `i` and `j` within the board?)

Comment: I think you want to make board a numpy array, and I think you may want to find a way to differentiate between red and black tokens.

Comment: I added more code to the question. As for your second comment, are you recommending that I put all the if statements in a for loop, would that allow me to not have to specify the i and j arguments? @Amber

Comment: I thought I did differentiate between my tokens, by making a player1_token variable and a player2_token variable. Can you please elaborate ? @mikey

Comment: Did you want the arguments to be set to a default value?

Comment: @EmilyRivas I was typing as the question was edited. Not sure if I goofed originally, but how are the tokens input into positions? Assuming your unshown function works with arrays, ignore my comment.

Comment: I input the tokens by making three different if statements. for the first one I input the player1_token into the check_win function as so; `check_win(player1_token)`and I do this with the player2_token as well. If that answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the function check_win with three arguments, but you call it with one. As was already suggested in a comment, I would guess that what you're looking for is something with i and j in for loops rather than as arguments. Perhaps something like this:

```
    def check_win(token):
        for i in range(0, 6):
            for j in range(0, 6):
                if i-3 in range(0, 6) and j+3 in range(0,6):
                    if board[i][j] == token and board[i-1][j+1] == token and board[i-2][j+2] == token and board[i-3][j+3] == token:
                        return True
                if i-3 in range(0, 6) and j-3 in range(0,6):
                    if board[i][j] == token and board[i-1][j-1] == token and board[i-2][j-2] == token and board[i-3][j-3] == token:
                        return True
                if j+3 in range(0, 6):
                    if board[i][j] == token and board[i][j+1] == token and board[i][j+2] == token and board[i][j+3] == token:
                        return True
                if i-3 in range(0, 6):
                    if board[i][j] == token and board[i-1][j] == token and board[i-2][j] == token and board[i-3][j] == token:
                        return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: i just used your suggestion but it made it so that a full board is considered  a player 1 win. Even if it didn't work it still helped me understand this more, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of `check_win`:

```
def check_win(token):
    token = [token]*4
    l1 = lambda i, j:[ board[i-p][j+p] for p in range(4)]
    l2 = lambda i, j:[ board[i-p][j-p] for p in range(4)]
    for i in range(5,-1,-1):
        c = 0
        for k in range(4):
            if board[i][k:k+4] == token:
                return True
        if i > 2:
            for k in range(6):
                if [sub[k] for sub in board[i-3:i+1]] == token:
                    return True
            for k in range(4):
                if l1(i,k) == token:
                    return True
                if l2(i,k+3) == token:
                    return True
    return False
```

Sample Board:

```
board = [['.', '.', '☼', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '○', '☼', '○', '○', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '○', '☼', '○', '○', '.', '.'],
         ['○', '○', '○', '○', '☼', '.', '.'],
         ['○', '☼', '○', '☼', '○', '○', '☼'],
         ['○', '☼', '○', '☼', '○', '☼', '☼']]
```

Comment: I have no means of checking its correctness. Can you confirm if it is working as expected? ...or maybe provide a sample board for testing.

Comment: No it doesn't. I don't know how to make a sample board for testing sorry

Comment: What case did it fail? diagonals?

Comment: Ok. I made a test board. I can say I've tried every possibility. And it seems fine to me. Now I'm concerned if I got the objective of the game right. You are supposed to form a horizontal, a vertical or a diagonal line of four tokens. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I must've inputted it wrong, because I tried again and it still doesn't work

Comment: is it possible that I could see the test board you made ?

Comment: Sure. I'll add it to my code. I used different tokens but that shouldn't matter..

Comment: Oh! the board I had used was `board = [["."] * 7 for _ in range(6)]`. that's probably why it wasn't working

Comment: That's a blank board. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, why?

Comment: If you run `check_win(player1_token)` on a blank board, it should always return `False`.